# Linear maps send open sets onto Borel sets

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $(Z,\|\cdot\|_{Z})$ be a separable Banach space and let $(H,\|\cdot\|_{H})$ be a separable Hilbert space. Let $T:Z\to H$ be a continuous linear operator. Is it true that $T(A)$ is Borel measurable for all open sets $A$?

Equivalently: is $T(B)$, the image of the unit ball $B=\{\|z\|\le1\}\subset Z$, Borel measurable in $H$?

I'm only interested in the infinite-dimensional case, $\dim(Z)=+\infty$, $\dim(H)=+\infty$, as the answer is trivial otherwise.

Comment: A partial affirmative answer is "yes when the Open Mapping Theorem applies," i.e. if $T$ is surjective. We could even get away with this if we suppose $T(Z)$ is closed in $H$. However, I'm not sure about the general case.

Comment: True. Unfortunately, in the problem I'm interested in, I don't have these properties for granted... the only additional thing that I know is that $Z$ has a separable dual (but it's not reflexive).